# Woocommerce custom Plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, plugin-development, actions, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to access the ID of the product currently being displayed on the page. I am trying to do this in a separate custom plugin.
I have tried `global $post` and `global $product` and `get_the_ID()` methods but not working.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: CleverTap
Plugin URI: https://clevertap.com
Description: CleverTap plugin
Author: CleverTap
Author URI: https://clevertap.com
Version: 1.0.0

    Copyright: © 2015 WizRocket (email : support@clevertap.com)
    License: GNU General Public License v3.0
    License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
*/

/**
 * Check if WooCommerce is active
 */
   $somevar = 0;
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

    if ( ! class_exists( 'CleverTap' ) ) {

        /**
         * Localisation
         **/
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'clevertap', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/' );

        class CleverTap {

            public function __construct() {
                // called only after woocommerce has finished loading
                add_action( 'woocommerce_init', array( &$this, 'woocommerce_loaded' ) );

                // called after all plugins have loaded
                add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( &$this, 'plugins_loaded' ) );

                // called just before the woocommerce template functions are included
                add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'include_template_functions' ), 20 );

                // indicates we are running the admin
                if ( is_admin() ) {
                    // ...
                }

                // indicates we are being served over ssl
                if ( is_ssl() ) {
                    // ...
                }

                // take care of anything else that needs to be done immediately upon plugin instantiation, here in the constructor
                add_action( 'admin_init', array( &$this, 'clevertap_admin_init'));
                add_action( 'admin_menu', array( &$this, 'clevertap_admin_menu') );

                add_action('wp_head', array( &$this, 'embedajs'));
                add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', array( &$this, 'add'));

            }

            public function add(){
                GLOBAL $somevar;
                $somevar++; 
                //get the current product id...in $id
                $id=;
                $p=WC()->product_factory->get_product($id)->get_title();
                echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $p . "' );</script>";
            }

            /**
             * Take care of anything that needs woocommerce to be loaded.  
             * For instance, if you need access to the $woocommerce global
             */
            public function woocommerce_loaded() {
                // 
            }

            /**
             * Take care of anything that needs all plugins to be loaded
             */
            public function plugins_loaded() {
                // ...
            }

            /**
             * Override any of the template functions from woocommerce/woocommerce-template.php 
             * with our own template functions file
             */
            public function include_template_functions() {
                include( 'clevertap-template.php' );
            }

        // finally instantiate our plugin class and add it to the set of globals
        $GLOBALS['clevertap'] = new CleverTap();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or which action hook to use?

Please if anyone could help!

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be using `&$this` when registering hooks, it's a PHP4 holdover, also the product is a post of type product, and should be the current post, but I know nothing about that hook, and when it's called. You'll need WooCommerce expertise, not WordPress expertise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the number of args you want to pass to hook function...

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', array( &$this, 'add'), 10, 2);
```

in this case I am passing a 2...the second arg is the product_id...

Now pick up the product_id here like this...

```
public function add($instance, $product_id){
                GLOBAL $somevar;
```

Comment: Hi Scriptonomy I had solved the problem earlier with the said method but still you helped me. Thanks for it. Ticked